# Trying to read a specific line from a text file with user input using Array not ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I've figured out how to read, store, and display contents from a text file into an Array, but my problem is getting only a specific line outputted when a user presses a number.. e.g. if a user enters 3, it should show everything in the third line of the text file.. Here's a snippet of what i have so far. text file would contain something like john, doe, johndoe@gmail.com, 10101, blue, 342.21. Thanks!

```
public static void readLine(Record[] objects) 
throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    File fileobject = new File(filename);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(fileobject);

        String[] array;
        System.out.println("Enter the record you would like to see: ");
        int userChoice = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < userChoice; i++) {
                objects[i] = new Record();
                array = input.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", "").split(",");

                objects[i].firstname = array[0];
                String name = array[0];

                objects[i].lastname = array[1];
                String lastname = array[1];

                objects[i].email = array[2];
                String email = array[2];

                objects[i].idnumber = Double.parseDouble(array[3]);
                double idnumber = Double.parseDouble(array[3]);

                objects[i].color = array[4];
                String color = array[4];

                objects[i].balance = Double.parseDouble(array[5]);
                double balance = Double.parseDouble(array[5]);


                passThis(name, lastname, email, idnumber, color, balance, userChoice);
        }      
    }

    public static void passThis(String firstname, String lastname, String email, double idnumber, String color, double balance, int userChoice) {

           System.out.println(firstname + " " + " " + lastname + " " + email + " " + (int)idnumber + " " + color + " " + balance);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: Don't use Scanner for reading files. It's actually quite slow however it's most likely alright for your use-case. You might want to try something along these lines:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the record you would like to see: ");
int userChoice = in.nextInt();

// Try With Resources is used here to auto-close the reader.    
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
    String line;
    int counter = 0;
    // String[] myArray = {};
    while ((line = reader.readLine().trim()) != null) {
        if (line.equals("")) {
            continue;
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter == userChoice) {
            // myArray = line.split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}");
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray).replaceAll("[,\\[\\]]", ""));
            // If you want to use an Array then un-comment the 
            // 3 lines above and comment the line below.
            System.out.println(line.replace(", ", " "));
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int userChoice = in.nextInt();
 for (int i = 0; i < userChoice; i++) {
```

I think you don't need `for` loop. Just use `userChoise` like `[userChoise-1]`.